# Properties of a relation on $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Q \times\mathbb Q$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Is my proof of the following excersize sufficient?
I am given two relations and i am supposed to show whether they are reflexive, transitive and symmetric.

Given $ R\subseteq\mathbb Z \times\mathbb Z  $

1. $xRy \iff x= \sqrt{y^2}  $

**reflexivity**: i) show a counter example that if $ x = -5 $ it follows $ -5 \neq 5 $ Thus R is not Reflexive.

**symetric property**: Here i am not sure if this is a proof or not,  my idea is that, it follows from the observation that only non negative numbers are in relation and only with itself. Therefore,

$\implies $ $x = \sqrt{y^2} $ $\implies $ $y = \sqrt{x^2} $ and thus the relation R is symmetric.

**transitivity**: From the definition of transitivity of a relation, if  $ $ $x = \sqrt{y^2} $ $\land$ $ $$ y = \sqrt{z^2}$ $\implies $ $x = \sqrt{z^2} $
Again, we observed how the relation looks like, so when we choose $z=y=x$ the relation is Transitive.

Given $  S\subseteq  ℚ \times ℚ  $

2. $xSy \iff \exists  z $$\;\in$$\; ℚ $: $x\le z\le y$

**reflexivity**: My observation is that we can not find a $z:\ $z $ \neq$  3 $\ $between for example $3\le z\le 3$  thus S is not reflexive.

**symetric property**: In order for S to be symmetric we need $x\le z\le y$ $\implies$ $y\le z\le x$
I show a counter example: $xSy$  for $(x,y) = (3,5)$ and $z=4$,  but $ySx$ does not hold. therefore not symmetric.

**transitivity**: $x\le z\le y \quad  \land  \quad  y\le z\le w$ $\implies$ $x\le z\le w$ if we choose $y=z$  it holds, so S is transitive.

**Is this a valid solution?**

Comment: Usually what you want to do is show that some condition (like reflexivity) holds for all possible values, but some of your proofs it looks like you're just trying to give a single value for which a condition holds.

Comment: Do you mean by Q and Z; rationals and integers respectively? i.e. do you mean this: $\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Yes,  I ment those. Edited it already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning $R\subset\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$. I would rewrite the relation by $xRy\iff x=|y|$.

- Correct, the relation is not reflexive since $-5\neq|-5|$.
- The relation is not symmetric. We have e.g. $5=|-5|$ but not $-5=|5|$.
- The relation is transitive: $x=|y|\wedge y=|z|\implies x=||z||$ and we have $||z||=|z|$.

---

Concerning $S\subset\mathbb Q\times\mathbb Q$.

- The relation is reflexive since $x\leq x\leq x$ is true for every $x\in\mathbb Q$. Your reasoning makes no sense because it is not requested that $z\neq3$
- Correct, not symmetric.
- Correct, transitive.

Answer (score 0):

$5R(-5)$ but as you already showed, $-5$ is not related to $5$. So it is not symmetric.